# What happens if someone ask while a transaction is happening?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Am reading [this tutorial about transactions](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-transaction/), however, I have some doubts about it and can't find an answer.

Lets supose a system where the server (back-end) has this scenario to borrow money to someone (user account A borrows money to user account B):

```
 1. Ask to Database the money of user account A
 2. Check in the server if it is enough to complete the payment
 3. Make a stereotypical transaction for that in the Database
```

After this, user account A runs out of money.

However, like the article mentions, if user A shares the account with user C, and user C try to make the same operation (borrow to B), at the same time, in the first step (retrieve money from the database of user account C, which is the same as user account A), this query will answer with the previous value. Thus it will have enough money to make this transaction.

Is my approach correct?

How could I fix this? Would I need an internal proccedure?

Thank you.

Comment: Read this [Concurrency](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/transaction-iso.html) in the docs.

Comment: I've been reading about it, but honestly it's quite confusiong for me. It says "Read Committed is the default isolation level in PostgreSQL. ...  two successive SELECT commands can see different data, even though they are within a single transaction, if other transactions commit changes after the first SELECT starts and before the second SELECT starts. ". That means that in my example if the commit happens before, everything it's fine, but if is not, I would have to handle with some constraints (Check balance >= 0) but what happens then with thinks like youtube views counters?

Comment: Well you need to read about the other isolation levels also, to get an idea of what is possible. Have no idea what you are trying to say about YouTube counters? Though beware that most things like that are approximations at a point in time.

Comment: I mean in things like youtube views, or like counts, things like that. Is not easier to "update" those values on each view or like, and bring the "result" than make a "Select count(*) from videos where id="...""? What do you mean with "approximations", I have no clue how those system works honestly.